# How do I load mysql table to memorystream?

Tags: mysql, delphi, memorystream

how to load mysql table to memorystream with delphi? If possible; making `select * from table where ?=?` will be very fast. but how?

Comment: What is your goal? which TDataSet? consider using `TClientDataset` and `TClientDataset.SaveToStream/LoadFromStream` or store it in XML structure...

Comment: I need to execute sql query in memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you have FireDAC, you could use LocalSQL to write a SQL query against any TDataSet descendent, including an in memory TClientDataSet or FDMemTable.

It's explained in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Local_SQL_%28FireDAC%29), and there is a [webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QA-xhfYoEq4) from the author of FireDAC demonstrating how to do it.

Comment: the memtable is support just SQLite. i need to like sphinx!
so; "select * from table" then i copy to memtable =>> i "select id from  memtable where full_text=?"